# How can I remove cmd+shift+left/right shortcut in Finder?

Tags: keyboard, finder, mojave, shortcut

How can I remove the keyboard shortcuts <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> (Show Next Tab) and <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> (Show Previous Tab) from Finder? I need those two shortcuts to select text while changing filename.

macOS Mojave -- 10.14.2 (18C54)

Finder shortcuts:
[image: Finder shortcuts]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In System Preferences select Keyboard, then the Shortcuts tab. Click App Shortcuts in the left column, then the `+` button. Next you will change the Application to Finder, Menu Title to `Show Next Tab`, and the Keyboard Shortcut to whatever new you'd like.

Keyboard Shortcut can be anything you want, but I might recommend <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> (for Show Previous Tab) and <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> (for Show Next Tab).

[image]

Repeat the steps but change the Menu Title to `Show Previous Tab` for the other shortcut

Comment: Cool. Didn't thought of this. By the way, does this setting sync with iCloud?